# Can I use underscore in url instead of hyphen?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

I would like to use underscore in my url instead of hyphen.
I mean like this [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages)

### My Current url:

```
www.example.com/2013/01/hello-this-is-a-test-post/
```

### Desired url

```
www.example.com/2013/01/hello_this_is_a_test_post/
```

But one good programmer in wordpress stackexchange advised me, Google treats `-` as word separator, but not `_`.

He also mentioned that rule doesn't apply for MediaWiki sites.

Is it true?

Comment: I can't say whether that's true but it probably makes sense.  The legal domainname characters include '-' but specifically disallow '_'.  They probably parse it based on these rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google treats hyphens as word seperators is TRUE.

The reasoning behind it I recall is based on programmers searching for functions which usually (if not always) have underscores in them. So instead Google treats underscores as word joiners.

This article elaborates: http://www.ecreativeim.com/blog/2011/03/seo-basics-hyphen-or-underscore-for-seo-urls/